# How to recursively retrieve files from folders returning file name and its Folder name

Tags: java, java-io

The code actually retrieves the files but In addition I would also like to get the name of the folder unfortunately, all I keep getting is the path to the folder. I need to extract the sub-directory's/folder's name that contains the files.

```
 public void listAllFilesInTheDirectory(String aDirectoryName){
   File directory = new File(aDirectoryName);
   File[] allFiles = directory.listFiles();

   for (File file : allFiles) { 
       if (file.isFile()) {
           System.out.println("File Name: "+file.getName());
           System.out.println("Parent : "+file.getParent());
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            listAllFilesInTheDirectory(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
 }
}
```

The output:

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `folderFullPath.lastIndexOf(File.separator)` in order to find the index of the `\` character before the folder name and then use `substring` to extract the folder name from the full-path.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the parent folder name without the path? If so, use

```
System.out.println("Parent : "+file.getParentFile().getName());
```